# Does a Broom of Flying work like a mount?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, mount

Is this item considered a mount? Is the character considered to be mounted when using it? Can he be knocked off of it? Teleported off? If he teleports, does the broom come along?

Answer (score 4):

- There's no mention of it being a mount, so it's not a mount.
- Therefore, the character is not mounted.
- Teleport doesn't separate a target from its items.
- Whether they can be knocked off is DM's discretion, since there aren't rules one way or the other, which is disappointing.

> **Broom of Flying**
>   Property
>   While riding the broom, you have a fly speed of 8 and can hover. The broom can carry you and your gear (up to a normal load for you). You take a -2 penalty to attack rolls while riding the broom.
>   **Utility Power Daily (Standard Action)**
>   Effect: You call the broom to you from any location within 60 squares of you. As long as the broom is not prevented from moving, it appears in your hand at the start of your next turn. The broom’s movement as it moves to you cannot be used to attack or impede any creature.